# Update value of a Node in a Linked List in C#

Tags: c#

I 've tried Linked list operations. And I'm able to add/ remove Node s in the list. But I'm unable to update a value of a Node in the List.

I have removed the current Node's value. So when I remove the value, will the node also removed?? or if the Node is still available Can I update the value of that.

Here is my Code

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string[] words = { "the", "fox", "jumped", "over", "the", "dog" };
    LinkedList<string> sentence = new LinkedList<string>(words);

   // sentence.RemoveFirst();
    sentence.AddFirst("today");
    LinkedListNode<string> current = sentence.Find("jumped");
    sentence.AddAfter(current, "XXX");

    LinkedListNode<string> mark1 = current.Previous;
    sentence.AddAfter(mark1, "ZZZ");
    sentence.Remove(current.Value);
    // I have removed the current's value

    foreach (string s in sentence)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(s);
    }

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: Why is this tagged as ASP.NET?

Comment: Why are you `unable to update a value`? Does `current.Value = "sth"` not work?

Comment: Remove does not remove a Value it removes a Node searched by it's value

Comment: You should use sentence.Remove(current) to remove the node

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to replace the node, just change its value

```
sentance.Find("jumped").Value = "over"
```

...

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string[] words = { "the", "fox", "jumped", "over", "the", "dog" };
    LinkedList<string> sentence = new LinkedList<string>(words);

    sentance.Find("jumped").Value = "over"

    foreach (string s in sentence)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(s);
    }

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: It gives a Null reference exception

Comment: because you removed the Node. Comment the Line `sentence.Remove(current.Value);` then it won't throw that exception

Comment: @tarzanbappa are you searching for a value that has already been removed?

Answer (score 1):

You are using the `LinkedList<T>.Remove` Method which removes the whole node, not just clear the value. see [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k87xw3hb%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)